# How can I choose the countries that have number of points in the top 25% of the distribution of number of datapoints with subset?

Tags: r

I have to select the countries that have a number of points in the top 25% of the distribution of number of datapoints using function subset & quantiles with the %in% operator.

My dataset has this form

```
head(drugs1)
  LOCATION TIME PC_HEALTHXP PC_GDP USD_CAP TOTAL_SPEND
1      AUS 1971      15.992  0.727  35.720      462.11
2      AUS 1972      15.091  0.686  36.056      475.11
3      AUS 1973      15.117  0.681  39.871      533.47
4      AUS 1974      14.771  0.755  47.559      652.65
5      AUS 1975      11.849  0.682  47.561      660.76
6      AUS 1976      10.920  0.630  46.908      658.26
```

where the first column represents the countries & the second the data points that each country appear in each year.

I tried to apply the command
a<-subset(drugs1, quantile(drugs1$TIME, 0.25),1)
but the results are NULL.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: *"that have a number of points"* ... how many points? Just some number, say `1`? *"first ... countries & the second the data points"* is inconsistent, second column is `TIME` (year) and it appears you have points in columns `3:5` (I don't know your data). Please [edit] your question and include the expected output. (BTW: it seems likely that this may need to be grouped by-year and/or by-country, in which case your data is not varied enough to be able to demonstrate well the process.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by figuring out the number of datapoints for each country using `table()`.

```
n <- table(drugs1$location)
```

Find the 25th percentile of the number of datapoints.

```
q <- quantile(n, .75)
```

Find the countries that have more than `q` datapoints.

```
countries <- names(n)[n > q]
```

Subset the original data to only include countries in `countries`.

```
drugs2 <- subset(drugs1, LOCATION %in% countries)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped a lot. I was thinking that the top 25% of the distribution, represent the countries belonging in q4 quantile ( 0.75 - 1). Do you agree?

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem so that it does not linger.